# How to interact with USB device using PyUSB

Tags: python, usb, microcontroller, libusb, pyusb

I have so far gotten to the stage of finding the device, now I am ready to talk to the USB using the devices protocol laid out in the [specification](http://www.barcode-uk.com/images/Promag%20pcr-MFR%20120u.pdf) on page 22.

libusb is installed on my machine and so is PyUSB.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# find our device
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x067b, idProduct=0x2303)

# was it found?
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

# b are bytes, w are words

reqType = ''
bReq = ''
wVal = ''
wIndex = ''

dev.ctrl_transfer(reqType, bReq, wVal, wIndex, [])
```

The above example is attempting to use a control transfer, which I assume is what the protocol describes.

I just want to know if I am along the right lines or if I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

The device is found, it's just the next part I am unsure of.

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: I don't really know where to start in terms of setting `reqType`, `bReq` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an example in https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst chapter *Talk to me, honey*

```
>>> msg = 'test'
>>> assert dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, CTRL_LOOPBACK_WRITE, 0, 0, msg) == len(msg)
>>> ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(0xC0, CTRL_LOOPBACK_READ, 0, 0, len(msg))
>>> sret = ''.join([chr(x) for x in ret])
>>> assert sret == msg
```

if you want to write to endpoints (bulk transfers etc) you have to obey the USB tree structure: `-> configuration -> claim interface -> get endpoint` ...

on page 22 of the specification is not USB protocol is GNET protocol (which i do not know). the point is that you do not need low level USB to talk to the device. you can use standard tty programs (`echo`, `screen`, `putty`, `socat`,...) on linux or something analog in windows

Comment: I managed to connect via PuTTY to the COM port of my device, however It is giving me no feedback (black screen), even if I type and blindly type commands i.e. `STX,N,CR` I should probably ask another question.